# How to detect bounce emails

Tags: python, email, imap

How do you detect "bounceed" email replies and other automated responses for failed delivery attempts in Python?

I'm implementing a simple server to relay messages between email and comments inside a custom web application. Because my comment model supports a "reply to all" feature, if two emails in a comment thread become invalid, there would possibly be an infinite email chain where my system would send out an email, get a bounceback email, relay this to the other invalid email, get a bounceback email, relay this back to the first, ad infinitum.

I want to avoid this. Is there a standard error code used for bounced or rejected emails that I could check for, ideally with Python's `imaplib` package?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message) has some good info on this matter. [RFC6522](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6522) gives the error code for any administrative message from a SMTP server as **Error 500**.
You could try listening for an error message with **Error 500**. That should work.

Quoting Wikipedia,

> The format for the reporting of administrative messages is defined by
> RFC 6522. A DSN may be a MIME multipart/report message composed of
> three parts:
>
> a human readable explanation; a machine parsable
> message/delivery-status, a list of "name: type; value" lines that
> state several possible fields; and the original message, or a portion
> thereof, as an entity of type message/rfc822. The second part of a DSN
> is also quite readable. It is essential to understand which MTA played
> which role. The Reporting-MTA is responsible for composing and sending
> the DSN.
>
> When a Remote-MTA rejects a message during an SMTP transaction, a
> field Diagnostic-Code of type smtp may be used to report that value.
> Note that beside the numerical 3-digit value, the SMTP response
> contains itself a human readable part. The information
>
> Remote-MTA: dns; smtp.store.example [192.0.2.3] Diagnostic-Code: smtp;
> 550 No such user here is sometimes reported as, e.g., while talking to
> smtp.store.example [192.0.2.3]
> RCPT TO:nonexistinguser@store.example <<< 550 No such user here

I'm not sure about imaplib though since I'm a beginner with Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your SMTP Envelope from address should not be the same as your RFC822 From Header address.  Then any SMTP errors will go to the bounce address, but any real emails will go to the From address.  Mailing List Managers use [VERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) to detect problems, by using a different envelope From address for each delivery.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid reacting to messages whose `Return-Path` isn't in `From`, or that contain an `Auto-Submitted` or `X-Loop` header field, or that have a bodypart with type multipart/report.

You may also want to specify `Auto-Submitted: auto-generated` on your outgoing mail. I expect that if you do as Max says that'll take care of the problem, but Auto-Submitted isn't expensive.